# Why doesn't OpenGL have circle or curve functions?

Tags: opengl

I need to know why OpenGL doesn't have circle or curve functions, unlike the rectangle and polygon built in functions.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What will be gained by knowing that?

Answer (score 4):

Because GPUs don't generally have hardware-accelerated notions of those shapes for real-time rendering. Graphics hardware is designed around a pipeline for rendering triangles, which are the primitive graphics geometry (and by extension can usually create the trivial additions of quads and etc). Any other shapes (curves, generalized meshes, etc) are up to you to create and turn into things that the GPU *can* render.

As a result, "allowing" you to build e.g. circles yourself allows you to control how complex the geometry gets. You wouldn't want GL to decide for you how much stuff to generate when you need a "circle"-- it will depend on what you're doing, how much detail/smoothness you need, etc.

Since it's no fun to keep reinventing the wheel (har), there are lots of higher-level graphics libraries that you might end up using that can easily create those geometries for you. But they operate on top of pure GL.

Answer (score 0):

I think at earliest days of computer graphics acceleration, the accelerator horsepower was a tad weak, so anything non-linear were considered costly. Curves happened to be non-linear in most cases.